# Woocommerce, update ACF field and short description with SQL

Tags: sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I've got a WooCommerce set up where I currently need to do two things. The first is to move data that is currently in the post.excerpt field to an ACF field that I've created specifically for the purpose while the second is to update the post.excerpt field with new data. All the product data is in SQL-Server Express because the product data came from another website that we're replacing with the WooCommerce one. I exported all the Woocommerce products with basic info like the product ID, SKU, Title and Post_Content and wrote a query in SQL-Server to match the two together. That's been exported as a flat file and imported into MySQL. Now I've writen a query to update the post.excerpt field but what I can't find is a way to update the ACF field in the same query (or another one).

```
set 
'wp.posts'.'post.excerpt' = 'updatelist'.'excerpt'
From 'updatelist'
where
'wp_posts'.'ID' = 'updatelist'.'product_id'
```

Can anyone help? Please don't suggesting importing a CSV file. There's 180,000 products and using a csv, well it's about 10% of the way through and has taken, so far, 24 hours.

Answer (score 1):

To update ACF fields, first i would usually prepare an aray of key-value pairs of ACF fields to loop over and update them:

```
# first prepare your array of ACF fields you need to update
 
acf_fields = [
    'field_5f70*********' => 'product_name',
    'field_5f80*********' => 'product_color',
    'field_5f90*********' => 'product_price'
];

# to find the key values for your own ACF fields, just go to admin dashboard under custom fields, select your group of ACF fields and then on the "Edit Field Group" you see those keys. If you don't see them, choose "screen options" and select "fields keys".

# Now we're going to loop over them and update each field  

foreach(acf_fields as $key => $name){
    update_field(a, b, c);
# a = $key
# b = value to be updated which comes from your old list (from querying your list)
# c = which post it belongs to (custom query for your custom post type that contains ACF fields)
};
```

That's how i update my ACF fields, there are other methods using `Wordpress REST API` too.